# Android Emulator Camera Black

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

I'm testing an app I made and I tested it a month ago with the same emulator. The app uses a camera and I used the `virtual scene` to scan a QR code on the wall.

The same emulator now shows a black screen when I use the camera. I made a new emulator and the same issue persists. I use the virtual scene for the back camera and webcam0 for the front camera.

I tried to move around using `⌥` and A/W/S/D (macOS). Nothing happens however. I also tried switching the GPU to hardware and device. I even removed the device data and cold booted it.

Does anyone have a clue why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

**Try wiping data on your virtual Android device.** To do so, open "Device Manager" on the right-top side of the Android Studio. Stop the device if it's running right now. Press on the three dots icon on the right, press "Wipe Data" and click on "OK".

That was a solution for me. But you can also **try to restart the virtual device.** Might help in a faster way!